# Why do Application Shortcuts in System Preferences disappear?

Tags: keyboard, system-settings

I have a longstanding issue with Application Shortcuts (ie. in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts). I can set up a new shortcut to a menu item of a specific application, eg. VoodooPad, and it shows up as expected, like so:[image]

This works correctly in the application.

But every such shortcut I have ever set up later disappears -- I'm not sure exactly when, but at some point the prefs pane reverts to the defaults (ie. just one entry for 'Show Help Menu', and the newly-added shortcut no longer works.

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score -1):

```
it sounds like someone has deleted your shortcuts or hit a restore defaults button.
```

I recommend that you

- setup time machine to save your preferences each hour. then you can use it to restore your preferences. that should help you identify the problem.
- setup a shortcut that you will use daily (maybe ⌥, to pull up system preferences)

hope that helps
regards

Comment: No-one else uses the machine, and it happens every time I set up an application shortcut, so I don't think it's a consequence of any kind of manual intervention. Something is clearly going wrong in how OS X is managing my application shortcuts, but I've as yet no idea what it might be.